# How much can I let the players know about the campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm, lost-mine-of-phandelver

I was playing *"The Lost Mine of Phandelver"* with some friends, but this was my *first time as GM*, and I don't know how much I can let the players decide about the campaign, about the history and about the rules we are using. I've been trying my best to always have control of the game but sometimes they are very resistant about following my lead.

Comment: Can you give an example of "resistant about following my lead"? What lead are you giving, and how are they resisting?

Comment: Also, there's a difference between your title and the question body. Are you asking how much _information about the setting and backstory you should share_, or are you asking _how much of the world the players themselves get to decide on and build_?

Comment: Do **they** want you to control the game? Do you understand the concept of "railroading"? Also, it's unclear what exactly you're asking, in particular when you say "about the rules we are using".